# Check if list contains another list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists, one containing lists of *album, file pairs* and the other containing only info about one photo - *album* (at position 0) and *file* (at position 1)

```
photos = [["Trip to Thailand", "IMG_001.jpg"], ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]]
photo = ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]
```

How to check if *photo* list is in *photos* list? Similarly like `photo in photos` for strings.

Position of *album*, *file* doesn't matter since there won't be any *file* equal to *album*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Similarly like `photo in photos` for strings*. Not just similarly, **exactly like that**. `photo in photos` works for lists inside lists too:

```
>>> photos = [["Trip to Thailand", "IMG_001.jpg"], ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]]
>>> photo = ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]
>>> photo in photos
True
```

Membership testing against a list simply iterates over the list and uses `==` equality testing with each element to see if there is a match. Your `photo` list tests as equal to the second element:

```
>>> photos[1] == photo
True
```

because all strings in both lists are equal.

Answer (score 2):

```
photos = [["Trip to Thailand", "IMG_001.jpg"], ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]]
photo = ["Latvia 2010", "IMG_001.jpg"]
print (photo in photos)
True
```

There is no difference, you would check exactly as you would for a string.