# Check if list does not contain list

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Firstly, sorry if this is in fact a duplicate - I have spent the last three hours attempting to solve this problem and haven't been able to find any solution.

### Problem

I am using lists to represent coordinates as `[x, y]`. I want to find out if a list of coordinates does not contain a specified coordinate. For example, if I have the list of coordinates `[[3.3, 4.4], [5.5, 6.6]]` and the coordinate `[1.1, 2.2]`, I want a return of `True`, because the coordinate is not in the list of coordinates.

It may be worth noting that the list of coordinates is generated using the OpenCV functions `cv2.findContours()`, `cv2.minAreaRect()` and finally `cv2.boxPoints()` which results in a list of lists. These coordinates are stored in a dict and accessed from there; calling a `print()` of the coordinates gives me the coordinates in the format `[array([3.3, 4.4], dtype=float32), array([5.5, 6.6], dtype=float32)]` as opposed to the format `[[3.3, 4.4], [5.5, 6.6]]` which is given when I `print()` the coordinates straight after finding them with `cv2.boxPoints()`.

### What I have tried

I have tried to use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872830/check-if-list-contains-another-list-in-python) but I get the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

The code for that attempt looks like this:

```
for coordinate in box:
    if coordinate not in specialCoordinates:
        # operations go here
```

I then attempted to use the answer to [this question about a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211828/python-using-any-and-all-to-check-if-a-list-contains-one-set-of-values-or-an) but I get the same error.

The code for that attempt looks like this:

```
for coordinate in box:
    if not all(coordinate == special for special in specialCoordinates):
        # operations go here
```

I also tried this:

```
for coordinate in box:
    if all(coordinate != special for special in specialCoordinates):
        # operations go here
```

### Additional information

The format mentioned above `if coordinate not in specialCoordinates` works when I try the following in the Python 2.7 interpreter:

Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a = [[3.3, 4.4], [5.5, 6.6]]

>>> b = [1.1, 2.2]

>>> b not in a

True

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You're close, but we need you to shorten this to a representative example, rather than a screenful of the history.  `OpenCV` isn't an issue, but `numpy` is.  Give a simple example with constants for your in-program structures, and *then* the `for coordinate in box` loop(s) you want us to fix.

Comment: If you have a list of arrays you can convert that to a list of lists with `map(list, specialCoordinates)`

Comment: You saying that python 2.7 works, so what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that the numpy array elements in the list have precision associated with them for example:
`a = [np.array([3.3, 4.4], dtype='float32'), np.array([5.5, 6.6], dtype='float32')]`
Which is equivalent to:
`[array([ 3.29999995,  4.4000001 ], dtype=float32), array([ 5.5      ,  6.5999999], dtype=float32)]`

Hence, if you look for [3.3, 4.4] in a, it won't be there so you might want to play around with the precision or do a bit of casting.

Comment: That is not the main problem. The main problem is that if you do something like `if (np.random.randint(5,size=5) == 0)`, you will get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Because it's an array of booleans and what's the ground truth on that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
#a = [array([3.3, 4.4]), array([5.5, 6.6])]
a = np.array([i.tolist() for i in a])

def if_not_in_a(A, B):
    for i in A:
        if np.linalg.norm(i - B) == 0: 
        #you can use tolerance like < 1e-2 to avoid floating point complicacy
            return False
    return True

print(if_not_in_a(a, np.array([1.1, 2.2])))
#prints True

print(if_not_in_a(a, np.array([3.3, 4.4])))
#prints False
```